# EditText that prevents adjacent spaces

Tags: android, android-edittext, input-filtering, android-input-filter

I have a requirement to constrain an `EditText` to never have adjacent space characters. It's easy enough to write an `InputFilter` to prevent the input of a space character adjacent to another one, but I'm stuck trying to figure out a clean way to handle deletions/replacements. For an example of where an `InputFilter` fails, consider the sequence (where I'm using • as a visual representation of a space):

> sit•a•bit

If the user deletes the word "a", the result will be:

> sit••bit

which violates the constraint. Nothing I can do in an `InputFilter` will help, since it is only allowed to modify the replacement string and, in the case of deletions, the replacement string is zero length. (In this case, I would like to automatically delete one of the spaces when the user deletes the "a".)

The only thing I can think to do is to add a `TextWatcher` and further modify the contents of the `EditText` in `afterTextChanged()`. But whether I do this in place of or in addition to using an `InputFilter`, this strikes me as a convoluted and not very efficient way to handle the problem.

Is there any better way to deal with this?

**NOTE** (In response to a couple of the comments and posted answers) I just want to be clear that I *don't* need suggestions about how to replace two space characters with one; that's quite straightforward. The question concerns the inefficient nature of changing the contents of an `EditText` from within `TextWatcher#afterTextChanged()`. At a minimum, making such a change always triggers a recursive call to `afterTextChanged()` where I have to do additional processing to ensure that the recursion doesn't repeat.

What I'm frustrated about is that I can get most of what I need very efficiently with an `InputFilter` but to finish the job, I need to basically throw out that approach and go with an (apparently) inefficient `TextWatcher`.

Comment: You can just use `TextWatcher`, with `regex` to limit spaces. No `InputFilter` required then.

Comment: `InputFilter` are not very well implemented, I mostly tend to use a `TextWatcher` instead of an `InputFilter`.